# Using validate in Shiny to hide plot without relevant data when using reactive function (R)

Tags: r, shiny

I have created an app using Shiny that displays data dependent on two different inputs. I'm filtering the data in a reactive function and then passing this through to the plots.

I can't work out how to simply hide the plots (and ideally show a helpful explanation) when there is no relevant data based on the inputs. I could do this if my data was in a dataframe, but as I have filtered it using a reactive function, this doesn't work.

I currently have the validate function nested in the renderPlot function, referencing the dataframe that is filtered by the reactive function...

Does anybody have any thoughts?

Reproducible code (if you select "Bristol" with the default date range, that demonstrates the issue):

```
library("tidyverse")

location <- as.character(c("London", "London", "Birmingham", "Bristol", "Birmingham", "Birmingham", "London", "Birmingham"))
dog_birthday <- as.POSIXct(c("01-01-2016", "02-02-2016", "03-03-2016", "04-04-2017", "05-05-2017", "06-06-2017", "08-08-2018", "07-07-2018"), format = "%d-%m-%Y")
dog_type <- as.character(c("Poodle", "Pug", "Labrador", "Poodle", "Poodle", "Labrador", "Pug", "Pug"))
dog_data <- data.frame(location, dog_birthday, dog_type)


ui<-       
  fluidPage(      
  sidebarLayout(        
    sidebarPanel(         
      dateRangeInput(
        "dates", label = h3("Birthdate range"), start = ("01-06-2018"),
        format = "dd-mm-yyyy", startview = "year"
      ),
    selectInput(
        "location", label = h3("Location"), choices = unique(dog_data$location),
        multiple = T, selectize = T
      )
    ),

    mainPanel(          
      plotOutput(outputId = "dog_type")         
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
 city_selection <- reactive({
    req(input$location)
    choose_city <- subset(dog_data, dog_data$location %in% input$location)
    choose_city <- droplevels(choose_city)
    return(choose_city)
  })

  output$dog_type <- renderPlot({
    validate(
      need(nrow(dog_data) > 0, "No data for this selection.")
    )
    dog_type_plot <- city_selection() %>%
      filter(dog_birthday >= input$dates[1] & dog_birthday <= input$dates[2]) %>%
      count(dog_type) %>%
      arrange(-n) %>%
      mutate(dog_type = factor(dog_type, dog_type)) %>%
      ggplot(aes(dog_type, n)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") 
    dog_type_plot
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the dates filter to the `city_selection` reactive and update the `need` condition in validate -

```
server <- function(input, output) {
 city_selection <- reactive({
    req(input$location)
    choose_city <- subset(dog_data, dog_data$location %in% input$location) %>%
      filter(dog_birthday >= input$dates[1] & dog_birthday <= input$dates[2])
    choose_city <- droplevels(choose_city)
    return(choose_city)
  })

  output$dog_type <- renderPlot({
    validate(
      need(nrow(city_selection()) > 0, "No data for this selection.")
    )
    dog_type_plot <- city_selection() %>%
      count(dog_type) %>%
      arrange(-n) %>%
      mutate(dog_type = factor(dog_type, dog_type)) %>%
      ggplot(aes(dog_type, n)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") 
    dog_type_plot
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! I tried using city_selection() in validate, but it wasn't working, so moving the dates filter must have made the difference - very helpful and better even without the validation issue.

Answer (score 1):

I also got an error trying to run the code:

```
Warning: Error in count: Argument 'x' must be a vector: list
```

A few other things that I noticed:

1. For me, `choose_city <- droplevels(choose_city)` doesn't do anything, I think you need `choose_city$location <- droplevels(choose_city$location)` if you're trying to remove the un-selected factor levels from `location`
2. <s>I think @Shree's suggestion will help, but this method still only checks for the location, not the dates. (The reason your version doesn't do anything is because `dog_data` is your reference data.frame, and it doesn't get changed by your subsetting)</s> @Shree's updated answer moved the date subset and now is probably better than this one :)

I changed your code a decent amount to get it to work for me (just because I don't use pipes and am most familiar with data.table). Obviously you can just remove the data.table dependency and filter with pipes!

The main thing is just that you want to check what `dog_type_plot` looks like right before making the plot. I added a `reactiveVal` to hold a message that's output in the sidebar:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("data.table")

location <- as.character(c("London", "London", "Birmingham", "Bristol", "Birmingham", "Birmingham", "London", "Birmingham"))
dog_birthday <- as.POSIXct(c("01-01-2016", "02-02-2016", "03-03-2016", "04-04-2017", "05-05-2017", "06-06-2017", "08-08-2018", "07-07-2018"), format = "%d-%m-%Y")
dog_type <- as.character(c("Poodle", "Pug", "Labrador", "Poodle", "Poodle", "Labrador", "Pug", "Pug"))
dog_data <- data.frame(location, dog_birthday, dog_type)


ui<-       
  fluidPage(      
    sidebarLayout(        
      sidebarPanel(         
        dateRangeInput(
          "dates", label = h3("Birthdate range"), start = ("01-06-2018"),
          format = "dd-mm-yyyy", startview = "year"
        ),
        selectInput(
          "location", label = h3("Location"), choices = unique(dog_data$location),
          multiple = T, selectize = T
        ),
        textOutput(outputId = "noDataMsg")
      ),

      mainPanel(          
        plotOutput(outputId = "dog_type")         
      )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output) {

  ## Subset base data.frame by user-selected location(s)
  city_selection <- reactive({
    req(input$location)
    choose_city <- subset(dog_data, dog_data$location %in% input$location)
    choose_city$location <- droplevels(choose_city$location)
    return(choose_city)
  })

  ## Value to hold message
  message_v <- reactiveVal(); message_v("blank")

  ## Make Histogram
  output$dog_type <- renderPlot({

      print("city_selection():")
      print(city_selection())
      cat("\n")

      ## Change to data.table
      data_dt <- as.data.table(city_selection())

      print("original data_dt:")
      print(data_dt)
      cat("\n")

      ## Subset by birthday
      dog_type_plot <- data_dt[dog_birthday >= input$dates[1] &
                                 dog_birthday <= input$dates[2],]

      print("subset by birthday")
      print(dog_type_plot)
      cat("\n")

      ## Get counts and sort
      dog_type_plot[, N := .N, by = dog_type]
      dog_type_plot <- dog_type_plot[order(-N)]

      print("add count:")
      print(dog_type_plot)
      cat("\n")

      ## Change dog type to factor
      dog_type_plot$dog_type <- factor(dog_type_plot$dog_type, levels = unique(dog_type_plot$dog_type))

      print("refactor of dog_type:")
      print(dog_type_plot$dog_type)
      cat("\n")

      ## Check for data to plot
      if (nrow(dog_type_plot) == 0) {
        message_v("No dogs to plot using these parameters")
        return(NULL)
      } else {
        ## Make plot
        plot_gg <- ggplot(data = dog_type_plot, aes(x = dog_type, y = N)) +
          geom_bar(stat = "identity")

        ## Return
        return(plot_gg)
      } # fi
  }) # renderPlot

  ## Message to user
  output$noDataMsg <- renderText({ if (message_v() == "blank") { return(NULL) } else { message_v() } })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```